# C++ AntTweakBar: multiple "variables" appear linked in some way.. bug

Tags: c++, user-interface

For those who know AntTweakBar:

When i make multiple TwAddVarRW (variables) that are linked to booleans...
(in total i have around 15 boolean bars right below each other)

When i "check" one... 4 others right below it (most of the time) are instantly checked too!
While the boolean value only changes from the one i clicked! How come this happens? bug?

**explained: (situation non-checked)**

```
bool 1 = false = "not checked"
bool 2 = false = "not checked"
bool 3 = false = "not checked"
bool 4 = false = "not checked"
bool 5 = false = "not checked"
bool 6 = false = "not checked"
```

***----> i CLICK/CHECK bool 2 button***

**(situation "2 is clicked")**

```
bool 1 = false = "not checked"
bool 2 = true  = "checked"
bool 3 = false = "checked"
bool 4 = false = "checked"
bool 5 = false = "checked"
bool 6 = false = "checked"
```

**(situation how it should be)**

```
bool 1 = false = "not checked"
bool 2 = true  = "checked"
bool 3 = false = "not checked"
bool 4 = false = "not checked"
bool 5 = false = "not checked"
bool 6 = false = "not checked"
```

But even when i uncheck one that shouldnt be checked, no matter which ones, they ALL uncheck.... :S
So its very damn weird... help me plz

Comment: Sounds like those checkboxes (?) all share a reference to the same object

Comment: If you have a `switch` block in your code that control your checks, check for `break`s there, seems like you've missed some.

Comment: well the thing is that is is a library from a site, AntTweakBar.. but it doesn't have a forum! so it should all be handled, i just "link" booleans to checkboxes etc... rest is automatic! seems like a bug then to me

Comment: it does have a forum, but it's not frequently used: https://sourceforge.net/p/anttweakbar/discussion/

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Oke the problem was that the boolean they use, is sgiven/used as a reference! And we gave up that it is a "TW_TYPE_BOOL32" while it was in fact a "TW_TYPE_BOOL8"... so its reading the reference wrongly that way!
Fixed now ;)